# Error 1004 methold "range" of 'worksheet'_ failed

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all I can't seem to solve this error.

The error is on line : `lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row`

The codes above searches sheet "male" and "female" for matches on column A, K and M. If all 3 columns matches, the row from both sheets is then copied and pasted on sheet "Mix" .

Does anyone know the solution to this? Any help is appreciated !

```
Dim lastr As Long
Dim lastrmale As Long
Dim lastrfemale As Long
Dim lastrmix As Long
Dim malesheet As Worksheet
Dim Femalesheet As Worksheet
Dim mixsheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set malesheet = Worksheets("Male")
Set Femalesheet = Worksheets("Female")
Set mixsheet = Worksheets("mix")
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrfemale = Femalesheet.Range("A" & Femalesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastr = WorksheetFunction.Min(lastrmale, lastrfemale)
lastrmix = 2
For i = 2 To lastr

    If (malesheet.Range("A" & i).value = Femalesheet.Range("A" & i).value) And (malesheet.Range("K" & i).value = Femalesheet.Range("K" & i).value) And (malesheet.Range("M" & i).value = Femalesheet.Range("M" & i).value) Then

        malesheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
        mixsheet.Range("A" & lastrmix).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    lastrmix = lastrmix + 1
    Femalesheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
        mixsheet.Range("A" & lastrmix).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    lastrmix = lastrmix + 1

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Your instruction is doing too many things. Break it down into smaller steps, see exactly which call is blowing up.

Comment: @Mat'sMug What do you mean? Care to explain?

Comment: Is that all of the code?  I can't replicate.

Comment: @Comintern No. But the codes above should be able to run independently.

Comment: @mrwave - The code above *does* run independently.  Can you post code that *doesn't* run?

Comment: @Comintern the codes that I chose not to post are not relevant to the codes above

Comment: @mrwave people are trying to help you. They're telling you that the "relevant code" you posted does not produce the broken behavior you're asking us to help you fix. Seems like *some* of the missing code *is* relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that's blowing up is an assignment. The right side of that assignment is a *value expression*; value expressions can be pretty much as long as you can make them, VBA won't feel a thing. But the longer they are, the harder they are to read, maintain, and fix when they break:

> ```
> lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

You have no less than 6 member calls in that expression:

- `malesheet.Range("A" & ...)`
- `malesheet.Range("A1")`
- `[Range].SpecialCells(xlLastCell)`
- `[Range].Row`
- `[Range].End(xlUp)`
- `[Range].Row`

Make yourself a function that takes a `Range` or a `Worksheet` and returns a `Long` representing the last row.

Now you have:

```
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & FindLastRow(malesheet.Range("A1")) + 1).Row
```

Which could also be:

```
Dim rename_me As Long
rename_me = FindLastRow(malesheet.Range("A1")
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & rename_me + 1).Row
```

Which seems silly, since the row number you're after would simply be `rename_me + 1`.

Comment: Ahhh okay I get it now. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, your range definition is wrong.

Look at this line as a correct example:

```
If (malesheet.Range("A" & i).value = ...
```

Notice the range will resolve as A1, A2,.. etc

For the line throwing the error, what cells is the range referring to ?

```
malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Try break up the parts of that operation to confirm the values are as expected.
Set break-points or write the values to other cells for debugging:
e.g.

```
Dim temp = xlLastCell     '(does this value exist)
Dim temp2 = xlUp    '(does this value exist)
Dim temp3 = malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row '(does this return an int)
Dim temp4 = malesheet.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row   '(does this work)
Dim temp5 = malesheet.Range("A" & 1 + 1)   '(does this work)
```

Once you have confirmed the underlying values, you can hard code the values for a test of the range.

Comment: alright i'll try it out. Will let you know if I find anything

Answer (score 0):

I believe that below code you try to find out the last row.
But I think it will not work

```
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A" & malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

it suppose is

```
lastrmale  = malesheet.cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
```

by the way either cells or Range("A1") both are same

```
malesheet.cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1  = malesheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
```

or the method I love the most

```
lastrmale = malesheet.Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```